# Change add to cart stock error notice in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

When a customer tries to add too many of an item to cart, they see this error notice:

> *You cannot add that amount to the cart - we have X in stock and you already have Y in your cart.*

This behavior is included on [`WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L992-L1108) source code [at line **`1067`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1067).

I will like to hide stock details and replace it with:

> You cannot add that amount to the cart — we don't have enough in stock.

How to change this add to cart stock error notice in WooCommerce, without overwriting source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the said text without modifying the plugin files with the help of **"Say What"** Plugin. Follow the following steps to change the text:

1. Install **[Say What](http://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/)** plugin
2. Visit **Tools > Text Changes**
3. Click **Add New**
4. Fill the fields as per your need e.g.

   - **Original string:** `You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.`
   - **Text domain:** `woocommerce`
   - **Text context:**
   - **Replacement string:** `You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we don't have enough in stock.`
5. Click **Add** button to save the changes.

Comment: Easier option for non-developer customer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That is possible using `gettext` filter hook in a custom hooked function this way:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_add_to_cart_stock_error_notice', 10, 3 );
function custom_add_to_cart_stock_error_notice( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( $text === 'You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.' && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {
        $translated = __("You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we don't have enough in stock.", $domain );
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that @loictheaztec's code works except that the quotes need to be changed to single quote marks in the fourth line if you want to use quantities

```
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_add_to_cart_stock_error_notice', 10, 3 );
function custom_add_to_cart_stock_error_notice( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( $text === 'You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.' && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {
        $translated = __('You cannot add that to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.', $domain );
    }
```